# Char** in a structure in C : segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, string, struct, char

I have a problem, trying to use a char** in a structure, in C language.

The purpose of my code is to keep an historic of strings. The structure has 2 variables:

codeJuste, which is a string of NB_PION chars.
codesProposes, which is an array of NB_COUPMAX cases. Each case keep a code which is a string of NB_PION chars.

I'm trying to write into each case of codesProposes but I have an error of Segmentation fault. thank you by advance for trying to help me (Sorry for my english, I'm French).

Here is my testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NB_PION 4
#define NB_COULEUR 4
#define NB_COUPMAX 6

//Définition d'une structure
typedef struct _Partie{
    char* codeJuste;
    char** codesProposes;
} Partie;


int main (int argc,char** argv[]){
    Partie maPartie;

    maPartie.codeJuste = malloc((NB_PION+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(maPartie.codeJuste,"AAAA");

    maPartie.codesProposes = malloc(NB_COUPMAX * ((NB_PION + 1) * sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(maPartie.codesProposes[0],"BBBB");
    strcpy(maPartie.codesProposes[1],"CCCC");

    printf("1:%s \n",maPartie.codeJuste);
    printf("2:%s \n",maPartie.codesProposes[0]);
    printf("3:%s \n",maPartie.codesProposes[1]);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error (which line) and what does it say exactly?

Comment: o_weisman : I get the error when I launch the program, after compile. The error is "Segmentation fault : 11"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
maPartie.codesProposes = malloc(NB_COUPMAX * ((NB_PION + 1) * sizeof(char)));
```

To this:

```
maPartie.codesProposes = malloc(NB_COUPMAX * sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<NB_COUPMAX; i++)
    maPartie.codesProposes[i] = malloc((NB_PION+1) * sizeof(char));
```

And don't forget to deallocate everything at a later point in the execution of your program:

```
for (i=0; i<NB_COUPMAX; i++)
    free(maPartie.codesProposes[i]);
free(maPartie.codesProposes);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work too. I have the same error at the starting of the program : Segmentation fault : 11.

Comment: @clmt974: Well, it works perfectly fine for me... I "missed an `[i]`" earlier, perhaps you attempted to use it before I fixed it...

Comment: Thank you, I tried before you modify. Actually, your code works :) thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Change to like this:

```
typedef struct _Partie{
    char *codeJuste;
    char (*codesProposes)[NB_PION+1];
} Partie;


maPartie.codesProposes = malloc(NB_COUPMAX * sizeof(char [NB_PION+1]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly BLUEPIXY!! Could you explain me the difference between your solution and my old one?

Comment: @clmt974 You must be like barak manos If you want to use a double pointer. `MaPartie.codesProposes[0]` is a pointer in that case, but this need  pointing to area of `char [NB_PION+1]`. my code only have to ensure the area size simply because  is `codesProposes` pointer to `char [NB_PION+1]` in the case of my way.